# access denied to mysql root after flush privileges

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm battling with a strange issue here.
I am setting up an Amazon EC2 server, installed with Ubuntu Server 12 LTS, to serve our web app.

I installed mysql, and then had some issues with being unable to access with the root password I had set.

Suspecting a conflict with a possible default install (I thought I had checked), I completely removed mysql including the user.

Starting fresh, I set a root password which then worked. I set up phpMyAdmin, got that working, but then when trying to set a password for a user following an import,
I got "could not find row" error.

Upon some searching I found that `'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'` could help remedy the problem. So I went back into the server, logged into mysql as root, and performed the flush command.

I was then logged out of phpMyAdmin with an access denied error, and since then have been unable to log back into mysql on the server.

The full error is:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am quite confused, already spent a lot of time trying to find out what the problem could be. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be, that your import not only created your payload database, but also overwrote the database 'mysql' ?

Comment: Thats an interesting point and a definite possibility as the import was from a complete mysqldump from our current live server. 

Would an import allow the root user password to be overwritten?

Comment: Rule of thumb (but only that): **Never ever** overwrite the mysql database. The mysql DB definitly contains the users and their passwords, so, yes: your root PW will be overwritten, `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` will make that change visible to mysql in the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! Use --databases and include only your DB:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump-copying-to-other-server.html

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by my data import being from a full mysqldump, which I did now know would contain all user tables including root, which therefore overwrote my root user.

I guess there is a way to prevent either the export or import of the mysql table somewhere.

Learn something new everyday, as they say..